# useNavigate hook not working in React router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have two pages, `Dashboard` and `Quiz`. Dashboard triggers an event which calls the useNavigate function with the state.

```
const nav = useNavigate();
const goToTest = (e)=>{

    e.preventDefault()

    nav('/student/Quiz',{state:{id:1}});
  }
```

In quiz, I then use `useLocation` to try and get the data but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function Quiz() {
  const {data} = useLocation();
  console.log(data);
```

If i don't destructure data in quiz, it shows some json data, but state is always null

```
hash: ""
key: "(a key was here)"
pathname: "/student/Quiz" (Dashboard and quiz are both in the same directory as student)
search: ""
state: null
```

Comment: could you provide actual code snippets ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a version issue. This happened on 6.14 but when I updated it to 6.2 it works fine.

The docs had mentioned v6 and above, so I thought I was in the clear.

I'll leave this question up for anyone who gets the same issue.